# Проблема с выделением в Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm

Когда скачал Pycharm и настраивал его, поставил галочку на пункте, и забыл название, теперь не знаю как отключить этот режим выделения в настройках.

[image: 1]]

Answer (score 1):

Ты поставил Vim плагин. Отключить через **Tools | Vim Emulator** или полностью удалить плагин в **Settings | Plugins**.

Comment: Большое спасибо, сработало

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем понятно что за выделение.Судя по скрину, проблема в том , что ты нажал insert,попробуй нажать эту клавишу еще раз.
"Ins" лежит справа от "enter".
Просто есть ошибка,при которой при выделении insert сам включается.